# Multiple images appear on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been searching the net for a solution to my problem. I am trying to load five images beside each other when the user hovers over an element on my webpage. So far I can make an image appear on hover however what I really need is to make 5 images appear on hover in a queued fashion?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".Invisible").hide()
    
    $(".image1").hover(
      
      function () {
        $('.Invisible').stop().fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
      }, 
      function () {
        $('.Invisible').stop().fadeOut("slow");
      }
      
    );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="workbox1" class="container">
  <div class="image1"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="width:100%" height="120%"/></div>
  <div class="Invisible"></div>                  
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="workbox1" class="container">
<div class="image1"><img alt="" src="pictures/Monaghan Mushrooms.png" style="width:100%" height="120%"/></div>
<div class="Invisible"></div>
                                
                      
</div>

Comment: Try using the stack snippet to replicate the problem.

Comment: Should the images fadeIn and out like a slideshow on hover?

Comment: Thanks @Sleek Geek I'll do that from here on out.

Comment: @m1crdy yes the images should all fade out together on mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

Created you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5gtpdkm/)  that uses pure CSS (no jQuery). Basically we put the `opacity` to `0` and set a `transition-delay` on the elements.

Don't forget to add `prefixes` to the `transition` and `transition-delay`, ie - `-webkit-transition`, etc.

HTML

```
<div id="workbox1" class="container">
  <div class="image1">
      <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
  <div id="imagesToFadeIn">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
     <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image1:hover ~ #imagesToFadeIn img {
    opacity: 1;
}

#imagesToFadeIn img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

#imagesToFadeIn img:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: .1s;
}

#imagesToFadeIn img:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: .2s;
}

#imagesToFadeIn img:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: .3s;
}

#imagesToFadeIn img:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: .4s;
}
```

If you wanted the container of the images to be hidden, set the `display` to `none` on the `#imagesToFadeIn`, and then hover set to `block`